# Moving sum based on dates

Tags: r, date, sum, embed, rolling-computation

I a large dataset that I would like to compute a moving annual sum of a column. It has to be an exact year, so I cannot use rollapply as its based on a specific amount of days and not the actual dates.

As an example I have the following code:

```
dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2006-01-01'),as.Date('2007-12-31'),by='days')
num = 1:length(dates)
y = cbind(ld,num)

        ld num
[1,] 13149   1
[2,] 13150   2
[3,] 13151   3
[4,] 13152   4
[5,] 13153   5
[6,] 13154   6
```

I would like to have a rolling one year historic sum of column num.

The only way I have managed to solve it is though using a loop and a subset of the data frame. This is not very efficient and I was hoping someone could advise me how to account for leap years using the embed function instead, as it is much quicker.

Using the embed function, I have the following code that works as long as it is not a leap year.

```
b = embed(y[,2],366)
sums = colSums(b)

a = ld[length(dates)-365:length(dates)]
final = cbind(dates = a, rollsum = rev(sums))


head(final)
     dates rollsum
[1,] 13513   66795
[2,] 13514   67160
[3,] 13515   67525
[4,] 13516   67890
[5,] 13517   68255
[6,] 13518   68620
```

Do anyone have a more efficient way of computing a moving sum based on specific dates, and not number of days?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to your data, with the date one year ago
(accounting for leap years), and use `sqldf` to compute the rolling sum.

```
# Sample data
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date('2006-01-01'),as.Date('2007-12-31'),by='days')
d <- data.frame( date = dates, value = rnorm(length(dates)) )
#d <- d[ sample(length(dates), length(dates)/2), ]  # For more irregular data
d <- d[ order(d$date), ]

# Compute the date one year ago (you can also use lubridate, for date arithmetic)
d$previous_year <- sapply( 
  d$date, 
  function(u) as.character(seq(u, length=2, by="-1 years")[2]) 
)
d$date <- as.character(d$date)

# Compute the rolling sum
library(sqldf)
sqldf( "
  SELECT A.date         AS date, 
         SUM( B.value ) AS sum, 
         MIN( B.date )  AS start, 
         MAX( B.date )  AS end, 
         COUNT(*)       AS observations
  FROM d A, d B
  WHERE A.previous_year < B.date AND B.date <= A.date
  GROUP BY A.date
" )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work quickly, although it still uses a loop:

```
library(data.table)
library(mondate)

# Create table with sample dates:
dt<-data.table(dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2006-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'),by='days'),key="dates")

# Generate some sample values to be summed, initialize the rolling sum values, and add the row number:
set.seed(6540)
dt[,c("val","valroll","rowid"):=list(sample((1L:1e6L)-1L,.N),0L,1:.N)]

# Subtract one year (12 months) from each date, then subtract that from the original date to get the number of days
# Create a column to indicate the starting row number to sum from:
dt[,rowid_lag:=pmax.int(1,rowid-as.integer(dates-as.Date(mondate(dates) - 12)))]

# For each row, sum from row rowid_lag to rowid:
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  #dt[i,valroll:=dt[dt[i,rowid_lag:rowid],sum(val)]]
  set(dt, i, "valroll", dt[dt[i,rowid_lag:rowid],sum(val)])
}
rm(i)
```

The above assumes that there aren't any gaps in the dates.  If that's not a good assumption, it should be possible to tweak the answer.

Using embed is interesting--I hadn't heard of it before.  I started down that path but decided to go back to the loop when I couldn't figure out how to handle the first 365 rows.  I'll try to finish that solution and post it too, in case it helps.

I also considered the route that @VincentZoonekynd took, although using `data.table` rather than `sqldf` (since I'm more familiar with it).  But in my experience the "cross join" in this type of solution blows up pretty quickly, so if you have very many rows it won't be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses `embed`, but it may not give the desired results for the first 366 rows:

```
library(data.table)
library(mondate)

# Create table with sample dates:
dt2<-data.table(dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2006-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'),by='days'),key="dates")

# Generate some sample values to be summed, initialize the rolling sum values, add the row number, and determine the number of days between each date at the prior year (365 or 366):
set.seed(6540)
dt2[,c("val","valroll","rowid","lag"):=list(sample((1L:1e6L)-1L,.N),0L,1:.N,as.integer(dates-as.Date(mondate(dates)-12)))]

# Create a table with column values made up of each of the preceding 366 rows:
dt2b<-data.table(embed(dt2[,val],366))

# Set the 366th column to 0 if the prior year was 365 days ago:
dt2b[dt2[(dt2[lag-rowid==0L,rowid]+1L):nrow(dt2),lag]==365L,V366:=0L]

# Sum the rows of the second table, and add the result to the first table:
dt2[(dt2[lag-rowid==0L,rowid]+1L):nrow(dt2),valroll:=as.integer(rowSums(dt2b))]
rm(dt2b)
```

Also, the "valroll" column from my other answer (using the `for` loop) includes one extra row of "val" compared to this answer.  I think this answer needs to be tweaked, but I'm not sure.